# How do I extract vmlinux from an ARM image?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I am trying to extract vmlinux from Ubuntu's netboot kernel used in the `armhf` architecture. The script `extract-vmlinux` returns

```
extract-vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux.
```

It even fails when I try to use it on a normal x86 kernel. How can I extract vmlinux from this ARM vmlinuz?

Comment: What file are you running `extract-vmlinux` on?

Comment: @Gilles On Ubuntu's official kernel binary for the first Samsung Chromebook.

Comment: Related reports: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88621/why-doesnt-extract-vmlinux-work-with-raspbians-boot-kernel-img and https://bugs.linaro.org/show_bug.cgi?id=461

Answer (score 0):

How did you call it? Try `extract-vmlinux /vmlinuz`.